# Write "myObject." and display information like IDE's

Tags: java, object, netbeans

I would like to program something like netbeans or eclipse makes when you type the name of some object (myObject.)  displays a list of methods and / or attributes. I really do not know how to start, I would appreciate if you had any idea or some link to inquire about it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Google for "Java reflection" or look at the javadoc for java.lang.Class: getDeclaredFields, getDeclaredMethods, etc. and follow the links to classes Field, Method, etc.

Comment: This won't permit you to "type the name of some object", but you can pass an *object reference", obtain its class (getClass()) and continue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *[reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)*, say that you get the name of class "Immutable" from the user, you can do:

```
    String className = "Immutable"; // get it from the user using Scanner
    Class c = Class.forName(className);
    for (Field f : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
        System.out.println("f = " + f);            
    }
    for (Method m : c.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        System.out.println("m = " + m);
    }
```

Comment: I see, I had no knowledge of reflection, I'll check it right now. @laune thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of applying reflection to an object:

```
Object obj = ...;
Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass();
for( Field f: clazz.getDeclaredFields() ){
    System.out.println( "Field " + f.getName() + " is a " + f.getType() );
}
```